# How to zip VERY LONG list of files in environment variable: *** buffer overflow detected ***: zip terminated

Tags: linux, bash, zip

I am copying files over from one machine to another. I am only interested in files that are more than N days old, so I have used `find` to create a list of filenames as follows:

```
DAYS_OLD=7
FILEs=`find /some/path -mtime -$DAYS_OLD | xargs`
```

Now I want to zip the files into one archive:

```
ZIPFILE='myfiles.zip'.
```

I run the following command:

`zip -r $ZIPFILE "${FILEs}"`

I get the following error:

> *** buffer overflow detected ***: zip terminated

How can I zip the files (in the ${FILEs} environment variable) into a zip archive?

Comment: What's the point of `xargs` here?

Comment: Check the `-i` parameter of `zip` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
find /some/path -mtime -$DAYS_OLD | xargs zip -r $SOMEDIR/$ZIPFILE
```

Comment: You probably also want to use the find `-type f` option to restrict it to files. And remove the zip `-r` option as that is for recursing directories.

Comment: Also, in case some files have spaces in their names, use the find `-print0` option and the xargs `-0` option. So `find /some/path -type f -mtime $DAYS_OLD -print0 | xargs -0 zip SOMEDIR/$ZIPFILE`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find /some/path -mtime "$DAYS_OLD" -exec zip -r "$ZIPFILE" {} +` to work with *any* valid file name, including those with newlines in their names.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
zip $ZIPFILE -i@<(find /some/path -mtime -$DAYS_OLD)
```

the `-i` parameter tells zip to read the list from a file. The file will be simulated on the fly with the contents of the command.